# Python with fuzzy,pandas

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzy-search

I have two csv's in which the rows can be matched by the value in one column (after some tweaking of this column). After the matching I want to take some values from both off them and make a new, combined row. I thought of a simple script using csv.DictReader for both of them and then a double

```
for row1 in csv1:
for row2 in csv2:
    if row1['someID'] == row2['someID]:
        newdict = ... etc
```

However, 1 file is 9 million rows and the other is 500k rows. So my code would take 4.5 * 10^12 iterations. Hence my question: what is a fast way to match them? Important:
This 'someID' on which they are matched is in neither csv unique.
I want additional rows for every match. So if a 'someID' appears
twice in csv1 and 3 times csv2, I expect 6 rows with this 'someID' in the final result.

Comment: Are someID in both columns unique?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: instead of iterating, use pandas.read_csv() on both files, and merge them on `someID`. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
csv1 = pd.read_csv(path1)
csv2 = pd.read_csv(path2)
merged = csv1.merge(csv2, on='someID')
merged['new_column'] = ...
```

Pandas operations are over entire numpy arrays which is are much faster than iterating at the element level.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, but the problem is in csv1 have 14k records and csv2 have 14M records